# Build And Host my web application on my own private cloud

Tags: server, eclipse, maas, cloud, tomcat6

I have made a private cloud using ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have a maas main server. On that server, I want to host my web application written with java, tomcat and mysql. My maas main server ip address is 192.168.43.191 and dns name is ubuntucloud. So, when I call it from browser like (http: ubuntucloud), I can reach and see "It's work. This is the default web page for this server. The web server software is running but no content has been added yet" sentences. I can call my web application like (http:  ubuntucloud:8080/IRMultiAgent/) while running tomcat server in eclipse. I want to call my web app like (http://www.ir_multi_agent/). How to do this? ps: I omit some "/" in my post, because of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your Apache web server to forward requests to Tomcat using `mod_jk` ([The Apache Tomcat Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/)). Setup an Apache vhost which acts as some kind of proxy to speak to Tomcat and is also able to rewrite the URL. Thus, `ubuntucloud:8080/IRMultiAgent/` can be accessed at e.g. `irmultiagent.ubuntucloud/` ([Smart HowTo](http://binfalse.de/2013/10/integrating-tomcat-with-apache/))

Since you already configured the domain `ubuntucloud` to point to your server, you should be able to also setup such a DNS for `ir_multi_agent`. Both can point to the same IP. Just make sure to configure the `ServerName` of the vhosts directives in the Apache configuration correctly.

Comment: I followed your Smart HowTo link. I have little difficulty in creating virtual host. ServerAdmin some@body.tld
      ServerName yourapp.yourserver.tld
      ServerAlias ya.yourserver.tld  .. Can I add ServerAdmin,ServerName and ServerAlias as I wish?

Comment: Yes of course. Those are just dummies. Find all available core features and their meaning at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to add the name `ir_multi_agent` to your `/etc/hosts` file. In order to do that, edit that file using `sudo vi /etc/hosts` or `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and add the line

```
192.168.43.191    ir_multi_agent
```

From then on, you will be able to browse to `http://ir_multi_agent:8080/IRMultiAgent` and access your application.

To get rid of the `:8080` in that URL, you have two options:

1. Run Tomcat on the default http port (80) by editing the port number
   in its `conf/server.xml` file. Note that this requires you to run Tomcat as root.
2. Front the Tomcat server with a reverse proxy, which will require installing and configuring an http server such as **apache2** or **nginx**.

Now, your URL is down to `http://ir_multi_agent/IRMultiAgent`. To get rid of the `IRMultiAgent` context root, you again have two options:

1. Deploy the application as the `ROOT` web application on Tomcat. That is, put it in the folder `webapps/ROOT`.
2. Use rewrite rules on the reverse proxy.

There you have it, your own webapplication at `http://ir_multi_agent/`.

Before embarking on all this, please consider [Shakespeare's wisdom](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/305250.html). An URL is but a name.

Comment: thz for your help @zwets. I want to know again is how to run tomcat as root. Recently, I log into with my account "yumon" and tomcat6.04 and eclipse are all installed when i am with yumon account.

Comment: When I run Tomcat on the default http port (80) by editing the port number in its conf/server.xml, I've got permission denied 80: java.net.Bindexception Error occurs. It is because I'm not root yet?

Comment: Processes other than root are not permitted to open ports up to 1024 for listening. You must `sudo` start Tomcat to run it with root priviliges.